# How remove the option of dedupe in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Accidentally, I triggered `npm dedupe` and now all of my node_modules folders are being flattened. It reduces file size but makes looking for stuff harder. Is there a way to refer this, go back to the hierarchical file system? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to clear '/node_modules' folder and run 'npm install' again?

Comment: Yes, already tried that. But now overtime Icreate a new project the flattening occurs everytime I use npm install

Comment: Bump... same thing happening here.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> The `--legacy-bundling` argument will cause npm to install the package
>   such that versions of npm prior to 1.4, such as the one included with
>   node 0.8, can install the package. This eliminates all automatic
>   deduping.

First removing the "node_modules" directory, then running `npm install --legacy-building` should do what you want.

Comment: Not only this but in my case for an old code node 0.10 the app itself works faster when resolving and then running in a newer node version